# Human-readable version of special characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there a standard way in JavaScript to get a human-readable version of a special character automatically?

I need to report some invalid symbols after parsing, which also includes such symbols as `\r`, `\n`, `\t`.

When I encounter a regular character, I just want to display it as is, like this:

```
Invalid character 'a' at position 123
```

But when, for example, I encounter `\t`, I want to report it as:

```
Invalid character '\t' at position 123
```

and not as

```
Invalid character '    ' at position 123
```

Is there a standard way in JavaScript to do this, or do I have to code around this?